# How can I serve a react app via nextjs behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js

I've built a React app that uses Next.js to render the code.  Everything works as expected when serving locally via `http://localhost:3000`.  I've containerized the entire app by [following the instructions](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying#docker-image) (more or less) and now have a container that functions as expected.  However, like most apps, it needs to sit behind a reverse proxy so that I can access it using one URL.

The way I have my reverse proxy set up is a base URL of `https://secure.example.com` with `/app` paths that go to different programs.

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
  rewrite       /phpmyadmin/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass    http://phpmyadmin/;
}

location /roundcube/ {
  rewrite       /roundcube/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass    http://roundcube/;

  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path "/roundcube";
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location /reactjs/ {
  rewrite        /reactjs/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass     http://reactjs:3000/;
}
```

When setting up my next app (the `reactjs` location), I've run into a bit of trouble.  When I go to `https://secure.example.com/reactjs/`, the page loads but the related CSS, javascript files, etc. don't.  Upon inspection of the loading html, these files are being requested from `/_next/`.  My browser attempts to load `https://secure.example.com/_next/...` but hits a 404, which is expected since nothing is being served from that location.

I've tried a combination of setting the [basePath](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath) and then setting the `proxy_path` directive accordingly but it doesn't seem to help.  I've tried to code out [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) but there doesn't seem to be a good way to rewrite the contents of the resulting html to refer to the request path correctly.

The only solution I've found is adding a second `location` context for `/_next/`:

```
location /_next/ {
  proxy_pass     http://reactjs:3000/_next/;
}
```

While this solution works, it only allows one next app to be hosted and I would much prefer a solution where the rendered html is properly updated to either have resource paths be relative (i.e. `_next/someResource.js` vs `/_next/someResource.js`) or at least provide an option to add a request path.

I'm pretty new to reactjs and nextjs.  Is there a feature or function I'm missing that would make this work correctly?

Comment: have you tried `basename` prop at your `BrowserRouter` component ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `BrowserRouter`.  I'm using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) to serve my react app, not [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to handle custom/dynamic `basePath` or the ability to add an URI path to the beginning of references within the rendered HTML.

Instead, I took my working solution and used `basePath` to push everything one directory to the right of the root slash and then wrote middleware to rewrite requests sent to `/_next` to `${basePath}`.

I wrote a full solution as part of a thread within [next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/59904) Github Discussions board.

My nginx config:

```
location /reactjs/ {
  rewrite        /reactjs/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass     http://reactjs:3000/;

  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
}
```

next.conf.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  basePath: '/reactjs',
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

middleware.js:

```
import { _NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request) {
  // If X-Forwarded-Host is not set, then don't bother with middleware.
  const forwardedHost = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Host');
  if (forwardedHost === null) return NextResponse.next();

  // Middleware starts here
  const requestedUrl = request.nextUrl.clone();
  const basePath = '/reactjs';

  // const requestedHost = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Host');
  // const forwardedPath = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Path');

  console.log('basePath set: ' + basePath);
  console.log('requestedUrl: ' + requestedUrl.toString());
  console.log('basePath index: ' + requestedUrl.toString().indexOf(basePath));

  if (requestedUrl.toString().indexOf(basePath) == -1) {
    console.log('basePath not detected in request.');

    const pathForward = basePath + requestedUrl.toString().split('localhost:3000').pop();
    console.log('Will offer (proxy): ' + pathForward);
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(pathForward, request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

This allows files to be served properly and without an additional location context within nginx.  The only other issue I have with this is that `basePath` **MUST** match the location URI path being used by nginx.  In my case, I don't suspect this to be an issue but if I were creating an app that was going to be widely used, this may pose a bit of a challenge.  I would much prefer that this path be able to be set via an environment variable but my attempts to do so were met with errors stating that `basePath` must either be empty or set.

Hopefully this behavior will be added out of the box in the near future.